# TCPDF shows empty page

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

i am using tcpdf.php to create a pdf.here is my simple html,when i print html,it is ok but when i write pdf it shows nothing.

```
require_once('../config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$html='
<div  style="background:#2185E7;color:#fff;padding:5px;overflow:hidden;width:786px;">
  <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0;  margin-top: 0;padding-left: 17px;text-align: left;  white-space: nowrap;float:left;">My Company name: 2533</h3>
  <p  style="margin: 0;  padding-right: 14px;text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;float:right;">321 32111 4</p>
</div>

<div  style="background:#2185E7;color:#fff;padding:5px;overflow:hidden;width:786px; margin:10px 0 0 0;">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Elegant 3 B/R + Maids in , Dubai </p>
</div>
';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: please help me here,i am stuck from a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove css attr `color:#fff` in the first div. I don't know why but it's OK when remove out.

P/S:TCPDF don't understand attribute margin and padding. My solution is always use html tag table for layout all general PDF. You should try it.